# Getting 6A82 when sending SELECT PPSE Command

Tags: apdu, contactless-smartcard, emv

I'm trying to read the data off a contactless Mastercard Paypass card.

So I submit a SELECT PPSE command using 2PAY.SYS.DDF01. Here is my command APDU:

```
00 A4 04 00 0E 32 50 41 59 2E 53 59 53 2E 44 44 46 30 31 00
```

In the APDU Response I get the error "6A82", which is "file not found".

I'm stuck, Can anyone help me to read data from the paypass card?

Comment: The SELECT PPSE command looks okay, are you sending this command over the contactless interface?

Comment: yes im sending this command over teh contactless interface, i think that there is no PPSE in the card or the terminal doesn't support  the PPSE selection method

Comment: Please try selecting the PSE (1PAY.SYS.DDF01) first to see if it works. Otherwise that error means you have to try direct application selection.

Comment: Did you solve your problem? If yes, what did you do to solve it?

Comment: @Peter: PSE and direct application selection are only for contacted cards

Comment: @arved please quote the source of your info, as I do not recall the EMV specs saying direct app selection can only be applied to contact cards.

Comment: The direct Selection can be used in Contactless cards which don't support PPSE selection mode. @arved

Comment: @Sara Sare EMV Conctactless version 2.4 Book B Section 3.3.2  page 25 ```Usage of the PPSE is mandatory in Entry Point```

Comment: All MCHIP PayPass cards should have PPSE, your command is correct, I'm selecting PPSE with exactly the same command. For more information, please refer to https://www.paypass.com/Term_TA/PP_Test_Cases_L2_%20Oct_10.pdf
On page 14 it states that: if card returns status other than '90 00' in response to the SELECT PPSE command, the PayPass reader must terminate the transaction.

Comment: Hi, I hope you were able to find out what the actual issue was. Were you using an MTIP card for the case @DavidJaparidze was referring to, or was it something else ?